How can I make this variable wait for the fetch inside the weather.getWeather() method
I created a Weather class with methods used to fetch geographical weather info from openweather API.
In my Angular component, I am trying to call the .getWeather(cityName) which gets coordinates for a city then runs another fetch to the weather API to get the weather data for that city. Then that all gets passed to my displayCurrentWeather method which packages that data nice and pretty.
However when calling the getWeather() method from my component class, and assigning it to a variable, I get undefined.
I figure its an issue with promises but I've tried several different variations of async/await and I'm not able to get anything.
Here is the class I created
export class Weather {
  static displayCurrentWeather(data: {
    temp: number;
    feels_like: number;
    temp_min: number;
    temp_max: number;
    pressure: number;
    humidity: number;
  }) {
    return data;
  }

  static fetchWeatherByCoordinates(coords: {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
  }) {
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${coords.latitude}&lon=${coords.longitude}&units=imperial&appid=${apikey}`
    )
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.main);
        console.log(data.weather);
        Weather.displayCurrentWeather(data.main);
      });
  }

  getWeather(cityName: string) {
    let coords;
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${cityName}&limit=1&appid=${key}`
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        coords = {
          latitude: data[0].lat,
          longitude: data[0].lon,
        };
        Weather.fetchWeatherByCoordinates(coords);
      });
  }
}

And here is the component class where I am calling this method:
export class SearchBar {
  inputValue: string = '';

  fetchWeather() {
    const weather = new Weather();
    let data = weather.getWeather(this.inputValue);  // <---- Data comes back undefined
    console.log('Data ' + data);
  }
}```



Two problems, you're never returning any values, and you're never awaiting any results.

Few errors in your code:

Your fetchWeatherByCoordinates and getWeather don't return any value, both should return a Promise.

The same thing in the callback .then(), you are calling the method but not returning any value.

As the getWeather returns a Promise after you fix both points mentioned above, you need to use async/await to get the value from the Promise, or use the .then() callback.


static fetchWeatherByCoordinates(coords: {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
  }) {
    return fetch(
       `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${coords.latitude}&lon=${coords.longitude}&units=imperial&appid=${apikey}`
     )
     .then(function (response) {
       return response.json();
     })
     .then(function (data) {
       console.log(data.main);
       console.log(data.weather);
       return Weather.displayCurrentWeather(data.main);
     })
  );
}

getWeather(cityName: string) {
  let coords;
  return fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${cityName}&limit=1&appid=${key}`
    )
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      coords = {
        latitude: data[0].lat,
        longitude: data[0].lon,
      };
      return Weather.fetchWeatherByCoordinates(coords);
    })
  );
}

async fetchWeather() {
  const weather = new Weather();
  let data = await weather.getWeather(this.inputValue);
  console.log('Data ', data);
}

// Or
// fetchWeather() {
//   const weather = new Weather();
//   let data = weather.getWeather(this.inputValue)
//     .then((data: any) => console.log('Data ', data));
// }

